# How to create an overview API for statistics with the Django REST framework

Tags: django

Currently, I have such a view and serializer, but how can I create an overview API for statistics?

serializers.py

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_hms(self, obj):
        return Example.objects.count()
```

views.py

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.example.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

`total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is used to display the number of Examples, but with this code, only one is needed since it is originally an overview, but the total is displayed as many as there are models.
How can I create a View and Serializer that is not associated with a model?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correct you can do something like this.

serializers.py

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_hms(self, obj):
        return Example.objects.count()
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ExampleViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
         serializer = ExampleSerializer()
         return Response(serializer.data)
```